# How to pass figure position to keyval macro?

Tags: macros, floats, positioning, key-value

I want to wrap a macro around figure-env to make my document more readable. Here is minimal example of how it is now:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter

\define@key{image}{pos}{\def\i@pos{#1}} % define key-val
\setkeys{image}{pos=!htbp} % set default
\newcommand{\image}[2][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setkeys{image}{#1}% set passed key-vals
  \begin{figure}[\i@pos] % use positon
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}}
  \end{figure}
  \endgroup%}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

but it seems that the default position `!htbp` is not set, because if i set it directly in `\begin{figure}[!htbp]` it works perfectly fine and the images are positioned correctly.

**Edit:**
I added `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` as suggested in the comments to make it compileable.

I appreciate you help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\centerline` shouldn't usually be used in latex (it is a relic of the plain tex base) and it does nothing with an image that is `\textwidth` wide.

Comment: @cfr: Thank you for the advice I added the two lines.
@DavidCarlisle: I did not know that but actually `\textwidth` her is only because I usually provide more parameters where the images are scaled down if it looks better. Is there a better way to center it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\begin{figure}` doesn't expand the optional argument; when expansion happens it's too late.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% draft is just for the example

\makeatletter

\define@key{image}{pos}{\def\i@pos{#1}} % define key-val
\setkeys{image}{pos=!htbp} % set default
\newcommand{\image}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{image}{#1}% set passed key-vals
  \def\@temp{\begin{figure}}%
  \expandafter\@temp\expandafter[\i@pos]% use position
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}
  \end{figure}
  \endgroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text

\image[pos=!htbp]{foo}

Some other text
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, since the value given to `pos` is formed by unexpandable tokens,

```
\newcommand{\image}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{image}{#1}% set passed key-vals
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\begin{figure}[\i@pos]}\x % use position
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}
  \end{figure}
  \endgroup}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfecly. I came across those expanding stuff quite often but did not understand it, can you first explain how it works and secondly what the exact difference between the first and the second solution is?

Comment: I just came across another question, why is it only this argument I have to treat differently?

Comment: @satanik In the first definition of `\image`, `\@temp` becomes `\begin{figure}` after `[\i@pos]` has become `[!htbp]` (it's a common trick for jumping over many tokens without needing a hord of `\expandafter`. The second definition fully expands (but `\begin` is left intact); choosing which one depends on the nature of the macro we want to expand and whether we want full expansion rather than one level only. Why this is needed for `\begin{figure}` depends on the implementation of the `\@xfloat` command.